# Meteor private directory files not accessible

Tags: meteor

Within my meteor app I've created a private directory.
With meteor v. <0.9 the files in that directory have been available in '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/app'

However now, using Meteor 0.9.2, the files are not there and I also can't access them via 'Assets.'

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Where are you trying to access them from? Client js, server js, css...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...whenever there is no JavaScript file present in the root folder of the meteor project, meteor somehow doesn't make the private files accessible (all my code is inside subfolders and packages). I solved the issue by adding an empty main.js file to the root folder, and voilà...the files can be accessed. I tried this across several projects and that really seems to be the issue. Very weird behavior indeed, since it doesn't even give me an error message.

Comment: So bizarre. Worked for me as well – in my case, I was having issues loading bootstrap from my `.bower_components` folder (had made the folder hidden so that it wasn't processed by Meteor). At first it was working fine, but then I had a similar issue where it couldn't find the `_bootstrap.scss` partial during build... your fix worked for me...

New to Meteor, I had previously tried to load Bootstrap-Sass from a [Meteor package](https://github.com/englue/meteor-bootstrap3-sass), then found out [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2796) was a showstopper.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a JSON file from the private directory, parsing the data and then inserting it into a collection on meteor startup. The JSON file is called `categories.json` with the file structure being `/private/categories.json` . The parsing and inserting code is below:

```
    var data = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('categories.json'));
    for (var i in data) {
       Categories.insert({name:data[i].name});
    }
```